# Unable to read private NuGet path while building asp.net solution Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I unable to read private NuGet path while configuring NuGet restore in Microsoft Azure DevOps.

The error is:

> Not found nugetConfigPath:
>   D:\a\1\s\https:\XXXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com_packaging\XXX\nuget\v3\index.json

Comment: can you share the configuration of the nuget-restore task ? it looks like you configured your feed as nugetConfigpath which is the wrong input field. there should be a switch where you can select if you want to restore from feed

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to read private NuGet path while building asp.net solution Azure DevOps

When you use nuget restore task in the Azure Devops, there are two options to select the nuget Feeds to use:

[image]

When you select the **first** option, you could select your private NuGet feed directly, like:

[image]

When you select the **second** option, you should specify the `nuget.config` in your repository that specifies the feeds from which to restore packages, like:

[image]

And the configuration in the feed in the `nuget.config` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureDevOpsFeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyCustomOrganization/_packaging/MyCustomFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>


  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <AzureDevOpsFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="xxx" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="xxx" />
    </AzureDevOpsFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

The reason for the error is that **you add the private nuget feed path to the second option**, that is not correct. You should select your private nuget feed from the first option.

Hope this helps.